# Presented or was presented?

Tags: difference

> Mr William presented with lower back pain.
>   Mr William was presented with lower back pain.

Which sentence is correct?

Comment: The first is medical terminology.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, the first option is correct. This is *medical terminology*.

> Mr William presented with lower back pain.

The symptoms that a patient has when first seeing a medical professional are normally referred to as *the presenting complaint*. Medical professionals use "presented" as a verb as shown in your first example. After they have examined the patient, they can give a *diagnosis*.

Your second example wouldn't make any sense in context even though it does sound grammatically correct. To be "presented *with*" something idiomatically means to be *given* it. Nobody gave Mr Williams back pain.

'Present' is also used in a similar way outside of a medical context and means to *show* something rather than to give it. For example, a military drill command is "*present arms!*" and means to show your weapon.

Comment: When I first heard it, I too thought it was weird. But that's how it's used in medicine. To present with a symptom.

Comment: @lambie the question has been reformatted since I wrote this answer. My answer is correct, I just mistakenly said it was the second option not the first.

Comment: I just have to say whatever. My answer here was clearly accurate on the first go. The reformatting into two separate lines does not affect my answser.

Answer (score 1):

> In medicine, a presentation is the appearance in a patient of illness
> or disease—or signs or symptoms thereof—before a medical professional.
> In practice, one usually speaks of a patient as presenting with this
> or that. Examples include:
>
> "...Many depressed patients present with medical rather than
> psychiatric complaints, and those who present with medical complaints
> are twice as likely to be misdiagnosed as those who present with
> psychiatric complaints."[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_(medical)#:%7E:text=In%20medicine%2C%20a%20presentation%20is,presenting%20with%20this%20or%20that.) "...In contrast, poisonings from heavy
> metal can be subtle and present with a slowly progressive course."[2]
> "...Some patients present with small unobstructed kidneys, when the
> diagnosis is easy to miss."[3] "...A total of 7,870,266 patients
> presented to a public hospital ED from 1 July 2017 to 30 June
> 2018."[4]

It is indeed to present with [symptom]

[presentation as used in medical parlance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_(medical)#:%7E:text=In%20medicine%2C%20a%20presentation%20is,presenting%20with%20this%20or%20that.).

This, obviously, is not how the verb to present is usually used.